# Elasticsearch aggregation to retrieve array of values associated with another value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working with an Elasticsearch index with data like this:

```
"_source": {
    "article_number": "123456",
    "title": "Example item #1",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "key": "Type",
            "value": "Bag"
        },
        {
            "key": "Color",
            "value": "Grey"
        }
    ]
},

"_source": {
    "article_number": "654321",
    "title": "Example item #2",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "key": "Type",
            "value": "Bag"
        },
        {
            "key": "Color",
            "value": "Red"
        }
    ]
}
```

The goal is to dynamically generate search inputs in a page where there is one search input for each unique value of `attributes.key` and within that input one value for each corresponding value of `attributes.value`. So in this case I would want to render a "Type" input offering only the value "Bag" and a "Color" input offering the values "Grey" and "Red."

I am trying to accomplish this with an aggregation that will give me a unique set of all values of `attributes.key` along with an array of all the values of `attributes.value` that are associated with each key. An example of a result that would fit what I am hoping for would be this:

```
{
    [
        {
            "key": "Type",
            "values": [{
                "name": "Bag",
                "doc_count": 2
            }]
        },
        {
            "key": "Color",
            "values": [{
                "name": "Grey",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Red",
                "doc_count": 1
            }]
        }
}
```

I have tried nested and reverse nested aggregations, as well as composite aggregations, but so far without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your index mapping looks like this:

```json
PUT attrs
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can achieve the desired results with the following combination of a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and its [sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-sub-aggs):

```json
POST attrs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_context": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attributes"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_keys": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.key",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributes.value",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this.

Comment: You're welcome! Hey btw I talk about practical aggregations use cases at length in my elasticsearch handbook. You can [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) which (other) topics interest you and I'll let you know as soon as the handbook comes out!